# Does every iOS project have only one window or does it often do so?

Tags: ios

Please look at the title.

And what situations needs two or more windows?

Thank you for answering my question. I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

It always has just one window. The only situation where you can implement a second window is when you want to display different Views over the AV-Adapter on an external screen than on your device (not screen mirroring).

Comment: Harry, you should mark this question as 'Correct' if you're happy with the answer - spread the karma around!